# Where can I find service pack 1 installer for windows 7 ver 6.1.7600?

Tags: windows-7, service-pack

I am searching for the service pack 1 installer of Windows 7 version 6.1 build 7600, and can't seem to find it.

Can someone help me and provide me a link for this build version ?

Thanks.

Comment: @Mokubai I tried the installer provided in the duplicate link, but a popup appeared showing: "Not Applicable". Maybe because I have a different build version ?

Comment: Did you download the x64 or x86 version? Whichever you tried you might need the other one.

Comment: @Hussein - No;  Your build number is not the reason SP1 did not install.  The build number only changed once with Windows 7 (when you installed SP1)